# Issue validating URL and TLD correctly with jQuery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a URL with jQuery validator, but the regex I'm using is falsely validating a domain with subdomain (e.g.: `subdomain.domain`) without a TLD as true.

I have this, which validates a subdomain:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domainChk", function (value, element, params) {
    if (this.optional(element)) return true;
    var regExp = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$");
    return regExp.test(value);
}, "Valid hostname required for player code");
```

It also isn't validating the TLD correctly. So, I could enter `subdomain.domain.aaa123` and it validates. It also validates fewer than a 2 character TLD as well.

**This only needs to validate for US viewers (so .ca for Canada or the like is not necessary to validate for)**

Comment: No point validating TLD. There are many new gTLD being added nowadays. Just validate the general structure and let DNS does the rest of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:\w+?\.){2}(?:com|us)$`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iN0cA0/2).

You can add more valid TLDs by adding`|<tld>` after the `us`.

Comment: This is my current implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/6e6pbyaL/

I need to be able to accept `www`, `http://` and `https://`, but its not passing validation.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It will match URLs in the form of `http://www.subdomain.domain.tld` (where http and www are optional). Is this what you want?

Comment: I fixed my validation to this: `^(https:\/\/www|www\\.|http:\/\/www\.)(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$`, but now I can't validate a URL without having `www` in front of it and it won't take a subdomain either.

Comment: @Matt Use the regex in my answer. Does it work how you expect?

Comment: @Matt use `/` around the regex instead of `"`. It won't work inside quotations unless you double escape the backslashes in the regex. Also no need to create a RegExp object, just use a literal: http://jsfiddle.net/6e6pbyaL/3/

Comment: Actually, double quotes `"` are needed. I figured it out and how to add variations on the protocol: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/6e6pbyaL/4/. Thanks for the help!